# .NET DateTime serialised to JSON for use in ExtJs JsonStore(event store for ExtJs Calendar)?

Tags: json, datetime, serialization, extjs, store

I'm trying to set up a Json Store for an ExtJs Calendar.
The store uses a Http Proxy to retrieve it's data.
The stores fields include startDate and endDate which are objects of type date.
I'm serializing data in my C# code into Json which will be requested by the Http proxy.
I am wondering should I serialize the start and endates as a string or as C# DateTime type.
At the moment I am serialising them as DateTime types.

The Json response looks like this:

```
{"Data":
"items":[{
    "cid":"0",
    "end":"\/Date(1275260400000+0100)\/",
    "notes":"4:00",
    "start":"\/Date(1275260400000+0100)\/",
    "title":"Basic""}]
```

The start and end properties look like some sort of date reference.
I have tried serialising the startDate and endDate's as strings rather than DateTime types.
This returns the following JsonResponse:

```
{"Data":
"items":[{
    "cid":"0",
    "end":"03/06/10",
    "notes":"4:00",
    "start":"04/06/10",
    "title":"Basic""}]
```

However, in both cases when the store has finished loading the endDate and startDate fields are undefined.
What should I do here?
I was thinking maybe i have to format the dates into a certain format expected by extjs?

Below is some sample code:

```
this.eventStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    id: 'eventStore',
    root: 'Data.items',
    proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
            url: AppRootPath + 'Calendar/GetCalendarData',
            method: 'POST'
    }),//proxy
    fields: Ext.calendar.EventRecord.prototype.fields.getRange()
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the documentation for Ext.data.Field - http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.data.Field . It has a property named 'dateFormat' that allows you to specify the exact date format.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it like this:

```
fields: [
              { name: 'Id', type: 'int' },
              { name: 'ResourceId', mapping: 'fitter_id', type: 'int' },
              { name: 'StartDate', type: 'date', format: 'd/m/Y G:i' },
              { name: 'EndDate', type: 'date', format: 'd/m/Y G:i' },
              { name: 'status', type: 'int' },
              { name: 'job_id', type: 'int' }
         ]
```